# How to make perl regexes matches ASCII and Unicode

Tags: regex, perl, unicode

I have a program to parse inf files of Windows Printer drivers.

System works fine as long as the file is written ASCII.

So, for exemple, regex `m/^\[([^\]\]*)$/` works fine to match sections headers.

In the case of a Unicode line, the line matches `m/^\0\[([^\]\0\]*)$/` and certainly not the first.  So, file is not correctly parsed.

How to make perl regexes ignore `\0` charachters?

Comment: [Config::Simple](https://metacpan.org/pod/Config::Simple#INI-FILE) should be able to read INF files. They follow the syntax of INI files. But I am not sure if it reads the things that look like comments correctly. I'd give it a try to avoid this problem all together.

Answer (score 1):

1) Make sure you have Perl 5.14 or newer.

2) Read the `perlre` manpage, particularly the section titled "Character set modifiers"

3) Use the /a, /u, /l or /d flag on your regexp depending on which behavior best suits your need.

Comment: The problem is that his text is encoded using UTF-16le. This won't help.

Answer (score 1):

You can't just "ignore" null characters. That way any non-ASCII characters in the data won't be interpreted properly

It sounds like you're trying to parse UTF-16BE-encoded data without decoding it. Use the core [`Encode`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Encode) module to decode it into Perl internal representation, like this

```
use strict;
use warnings 'all';
use feature 'say';

use Encode;

my $bytes = "\0[\0x\0x\0x\0]";

my $string = decode('UTF-16BE', $bytes, Encode::FB_CROAK);

say $string;
```

#### output

```
[xxx]
```

If I'm wrong about the encoding then please show a dump of your input string, using

```
use Data::Dumper;
$Data::Dumper::Useqq = 1;
$Data::Dumper::Terse = 1;

print Dumper $bytes;
```

Answer (score 0):

Always decode your inputs and encode your outputs. Specifically, change

```
open(my $fh, '<', $qfn)
```

to

```
open(my $fh, '<:encoding(UTF-16le)', $qfn)
```

This will decode the text from bytes into code points, allowing your matches to work.